# Can images be added to the Asset Pipeline at runtime / hot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sprockets

Scenario:

- Have already deployed a Rails 3.2 app, and it ran the asset pipeline flow…
- Now as a result of a user action, we have a new image and we want it to be a part of the asset pipeline for benefits like cache busting (though now I think about it, with user-uploaded images given unique filenames each time, that is a moot point)
- Is there any way to be able to / is it a good idea to use the asset pipeline at this point, for that new image?

I have a feeling this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling assets is just a rake task, you could invoke the task at any point. The task is `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html for more information.

However, I would not treat user uploaded images as assets to be compiled. I think doing so would be a bad idea.

Instead, like you touched on, make your user uploaded images have unique names. So when new images get uploaded/replaced new names will be generated. An example of this being done can be found in the [paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip). It writes the images to disk and saves a record/reference in the database. Those images have an id in the databases and the URLs involve that id. So you would have `/photos/4/nothing.png` and `/photos/2/yes.png`. Where 2 and 4 point back to database records with metadata/relations to the images.

Also, when you use the `image_tag` rails view helper it will automatically add a cache buster onto the URL of the image. The cache buster is done as a query string, so `image_tag('test.png')` becomes `/images/test.png?1234567890`. Sometimes certain proxies will not 'bust' query string caches, but those are a minority.

Comment: “However, I would not treat user uploaded images as assets to be compiled. I think doing so would be a bad idea.” It very well may be. My gut says that’s probably right. But would you mind fleshing out why that may be the wrong way to go?

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself first why you would want to compile these assets? What benefits do you gain, and what is the cost associated with them? Running a rake assets:precompile task everytime someone uploads an image is quite expensive! What can you get out of the asset pipeline with regard to images that you cannot do with the image_tag helper? There are some subtle benefits to compiling image assets, but unless they are requirements of your project then you are probably introducing too much complexity for an unspecified/unrealized gain.